# How to make all columns width fixed, for a datatable using bootstrap 4 and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, bootstrap-4, datatable

So I have this GAS Web app that lets you search for an ID, and it pulls the data next to that ID from the spreadsheet and then displays it on a data table right under the form elements

This is the code I have for the HTML file

The thing is the info for some columns is just 2 or 3 digits and for others there may be a couple of words, so there is quite some variance in width for the columns

Id been trying to adjust the width to 16.66% (I have 6 columns) but I cant make it work, any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <script>
          //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
             
          
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
        
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table-responsive table-sm table-bordered table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>-</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>-</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>-</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>-</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>-</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>-</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext">Search Text</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Search Text">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
              
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no percent adjustment for width in spreadsheet columns.  Pick a width and make it the same for all columns with Sheet [setColumnWidth()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setColumnWidths(Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: This is for the width for the datatable displayed in the webapp not for the spreadsheet, the spreadsheet is just there to retrieve data

Comment: So that is really an html/css question why not use an html or css tag.  There are several different ways to do it.  I'm not that familiar with it any more so add those tags and you might find someone that knows a lot about it. I just added the tags for you